# Design pattern for consecutive object value extractor

Tags: java, design-patterns, iterator, extractor, reader

Consider an object that extracts object values from a source on a "pull" basis, until a special value (e.g., `null`) is encountered.

In `Java`, the API could be something like

```
  public interface ValueExtractor<T> {
    public T extractNext();
  }
```

Operationally, this is an `Iterator` but it only has a (sort of) "next()" method and is not a `Reader` since it does not read from the source byte-by-byte. It also resembles a database cursor in the sense that it "scrolls" over all data values (records), until they are exhausted.

Is there a design pattern other than "iterator" for this use case?

What would be the best name to call such a simple object?

Comment: Why isn't it an Iterator? Looks like one to me.

Comment: In `Java` terms, it does not have a `hasNext()` or a `remove()` method. It is a "partial" iterator. :-)

Comment: remove() is an optional operation. Just throw UnsupportedOperationException(). For hasNext(), you can extract the next value and buffer it, so that the subsequent call to next() returns the buffered value.

Comment: In terms of the GoF design patterns and this wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern) I'd go for `Iterator`, too.

Comment: The question refers to a use case that does not have `hasNext()` or `remove()`, otherwise implementing them is obviously trivial. Yes, it is an `iterator` in operation, but I am wondering whether there is another pattern for this "simplified iterator" behavior.

Comment: Why do you care? If you do find this out, how exactly will it help you improve your code?

Comment: Is is basically about naming consistency. An `iterator` has a specific API and role in every language and the object I am asking about does not comply to any such API, even if its only method is renamed into something else. No big deal, really, I am just asking about opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an `Iterator`.  Just because it doesn't follow the `java.util.Iterator` interface does not mean it doesn't follow the Iterator Design Pattern.

The only difference is you have only a single method that combines fetching the next element and checking if there is a next object to fetch.  I assume you return `null` if there are no more elements.

Whether you have separate `hasNext()` and `fetchNext()` methods or if you combine them into a single method that returns null is an API decision and does not change the fact that you are following the Iterator Design Pattern.

However, from an API naming convention point of view, if you choose to have all the Iterator methods combined into a single `fetchNext()` method, you should not have the word "Iterator" in your class name since that could cause confusion from users of your code that your class implements the `java.util.Iterator` interface.

It doesn't really matter what you name your class otherwise so I would go with naming it based on whatever data it is iterating over.

**EDIT**
Since you say in your OP:

> It also resembles a database cursor in the sense that it "scrolls" over all data values (records), until they are exhausted.

You can probably name it something like `ScrollableRecords`

Comment: Good points and +1. I agree. But what do you call such classes? :-)

Comment: @PNS added name suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Guava has an [AbstractIterator](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/AbstractIterator.html) class you can use to make your ValueExtractor behave like an Iterator.

Comment: Sure, but that is not what I am after. Please check the comments. Thanks. :-)